# symfony2 queries not returning results even though login works

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am having an issue that I haven't seen before with a new Symfony2 project.  I have setup the authentication for the new application using a normal form login, and that works fine.
The problem is when I try to query the database using either doctrine DQL or raw SQL in the action of a controller.  Just for testing, I am trying to query the same user table that the authentication uses.  I made it a very simple query that SHOULD have results, but when the query is executed, no results are returned.

This is how I am doing the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sys_user";
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$user = $stmt->fetchAll();
$return = array("success"=>true,"data"=>$user);
$response = new JsonResponse($return );
return $response;
```

I have performed this query directly on my database, and it definitely does have data, so I am lost to why this won't work.  In my mind, if the authentication mechanism can pull data from the database, it doesn't make sense that I am unable to fetch data from the same table.

There is no error, just an empty result.

I don't know if posting from my config files will help, because it seems to me like everything is setup correctly, just the query isn't returning data.

Has anyone experienced this? Any ideas what I can do?

I am using:
Symfony 2.3.6,
PHP 5.3.27,
Postgres 9.2,
IIS 7.5

EDIT:

Here is my query using DQL.  I would prefer to use DQL for maintainability.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT u
     FROM MyCoreBundle:SysUser u'
);          
$user = $query->getResult();
```

This returns an empty result for each row in the table.  So doctrine knows how many rows there are, but won't return the objects.  Is there something I am missing here? This is a modified snippet straight from the symfony docs [Here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects) so I don't know what could be wrong.

This does the same thing as well:

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository('MyCoreBundle:SysUser')
->findAll();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the response.  This was how the response was returned:

```
$response = new JsonResponse($user);
```

This uses json_encode which expects and assosiative array as the parameter.  What needed to be done is this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT u
     FROM MyCoreBundle:SysUser u'
);          
$user = $query->getArrayResult();
```

This solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code after $stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);

```
$stmt->execute();
```

I think this might be the problem.

Comment: OMG, I feel pretty dumb now... that def was the problem with the raw sql query.  But see my edit for the problem with the DQL query. Thanks!

Comment: Yea the problem is definitely $user variable which is a collection of objects and it should be an array, the answer below is the correct one, using $user = $query->getArrayResult(); solves you're problem.